# Непонятно откуда идёт hover на тэг <tr>

Tags: html, css, hover, table

Столкнулся с проблемой - при наведении на элемент  таблицы срабатывает затемнение заднего фона всех ячеек строки, кроме первой. Когда пытаюсь самостоятельно установить :hover {background-color: red}, например, то красный цвет оказывается под этим затемнением. Вообще без понятия откуда берется этот стиль.
Когда в панели разработчика нажимаю Force state -> hover - затемнение появляется, но в стилях никаких изменений.
Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобным. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Могу дать телефон знакомой цыганки... Раскинет карты и узнаем....

Comment: Если поможет - я бы с радостью)
Я даже не знаю что кидать. Обычный тэг <tr>?))

Comment: видать,  где-то в JS прописано  `document.addEventListener('mouseenter' , .function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

Если при наведении на элемент таблицы срабатывает затемнение заднего фона всех ячеек строки, кроме первой то скорее всего :hover висит на tr, :hover {background-color: red} вы путаетесь установить куда? На ячейку? Тогда все понятно ведь есть же еще hover на tr. Или на саму строку (tr) тогда возможно следует проверить hover на псевдоэлементе привязанный к tr

Comment: :hover ставлю на tr. Проверил :before, :after - не подходит :(